# Create a group for branches

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

How can I create a group of branches with command line, Sourcetree or Gitlab? With group of branches a folder that contain all the branches from the same group, "feature" for example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In git, what you're asking for is called a "namespace".  The way I usually see it used, it's mostly a glorified naming convention; but it can be a bit more than that, as outlined here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces

You can name your branches like `feature/newThing`, `feature/coolFeature`, `feature/bugFix`, etc.  Internally this does organize them into different folders on the filesystem (for what that's worth).  More importantly, you can then address all branches from a namespace in a refspec rule, among other things.

If you're coming from a system like TFVC, where branches are literally organized into folders, this may seem a little flimsy; but then most branch concepts are lighter-weight in git than what other systems' users are accustomed to.

Comment: According to my reading of `gitnamespaces` (Git 2.40.0), this functionality is meant for storing multiple repositories in one single repository… or clients being able to fetch multiple repositories from only one repository (since they are stored in one database). While the OP seems to just be asking about branch management.

Answer (score 1):

Those GUI's typically group them based on `/`, so for example I have branches call `feature/email-login` and `feature/bcrypt-replacement` that would be listed as email-login and bcrypt-replacement under the feature folder. I would still check them out as `feature/email-login` though.